# Game of Fifteen (Swift): extra touch to confirm all the buttons are arranged

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, textlabel

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with the logic?
I make a game of Fifteen and faced a problem.
I need to be sure all the fifteen buttons are arranged in a proper way:

logic:
Every time a button is touched
1. function makeMove() changes the position of a button .
2. function checkGameOver() checks whether all the button are arranged properly,
   if yes, then function showAlert() make a pop-up window appear.

problem:
when all the buttons are placed, showAlert() does not fire and
I need to touch again any button to get the pop-up window

Thank you.

```
func makeMove(button: UIButton) {
        var currentButtonNumber = button.tag - 1
        if ( currentButtonNumber >= 0 && currentButtonNumber <= 15 ) && button.tag != 4 && button.tag != 8 && button.tag != 12 {
            guard buttons[button.tag - 1].backgroundColor != .none else {
                buttons[button.tag - 1].backgroundColor = .yellow
                buttons[button.tag - 1].setTitle(button.titleLabel?.text, for: .normal)
                buttons[button.tag].backgroundColor = .none
                button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
                return
            }
        }

        currentButtonNumber = button.tag + 1
        if ( currentButtonNumber >= 0 && currentButtonNumber <= 15 ) && button.tag != 3 && button.tag != 7 && button.tag != 11 {
            guard buttons[button.tag + 1].backgroundColor != .none else {
                buttons[button.tag + 1].backgroundColor = .yellow
                buttons[button.tag + 1].setTitle(button.titleLabel?.text, for: .normal)
                buttons[button.tag].backgroundColor = .none
                button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
                return
            }
        }

        currentButtonNumber = button.tag - 4
        if currentButtonNumber >= 0 && currentButtonNumber <= 15 {
            guard buttons[button.tag - 4].backgroundColor != .none else {
                buttons[button.tag - 4].backgroundColor = .yellow
                buttons[button.tag - 4].setTitle(button.titleLabel?.text, for: .normal)
                buttons[button.tag].backgroundColor = .none
                button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
                return
            }
        }

        currentButtonNumber = button.tag + 4
        if currentButtonNumber >= 0 && currentButtonNumber <= 15 {
            guard buttons[button.tag + 4].backgroundColor != .none else {
                buttons[button.tag + 4].backgroundColor = .yellow
                buttons[button.tag + 4].setTitle(button.titleLabel?.text, for: .normal)
                buttons[button.tag].backgroundColor = .none
                button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
                return
            }
        }

    }
```

```
    func showAlert() {
        var minutes = 0
        var seconds = 0

        if timerCounter < 60 {
            seconds = timerCounter
        } else if timerCounter == 60 {
            minutes = 1
            seconds = 0
        } else {
            seconds = timerCounter % 60
            minutes = (timerCounter - seconds) / 60
        }

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Congratulations!",
                                      message: "You spent \(minutes) minutes and \(seconds) seconds", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
                                   style: .default, handler: {
                                    action in
                                    self.setNewGame() 
        })

        alert.addAction(action)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

```
    func checkGameOver() -> Bool {
        var isGameOver = false
        var rightOrderCounter = 0

        for number in 0...14 {
            if (buttons[number].titleLabel?.text == String(number + 1)) {
                rightOrderCounter += 1
            } else {
                rightOrderCounter = 0
                break
            }
        }

        if rightOrderCounter == 15 {
            isGameOver = true
        }

        return isGameOver

    }
```

```
    @IBAction func moveButton(button: UIButton) {

        makeMove(button: button)

        if self.checkGameOver() {
            self.stopTimer()
            self.showAlert()
        }

    }
```

Comment: your question is like an algorithm, is it a homework question?

Comment: show your actual code.  Perhaps you are doing the check before moving the button

Comment: To novonimo: no, it is not a homework.

Comment: To vacawama: when check in dubugger at the very end of IBAction func moveButton(button: UIButton) {...}, I get the old oder of buttons and old titles on them in spite of the fact the buttons had got new titles. After leaving the IBAction func moveButton(button: UIButton) {...}, the order is new, the titles are ok but I need to press any button to call showAlert() and break the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is using the button's titles as your model.  The problem is that setting a button's title with `setTitle(:for:)` doesn't necessarily happen until after you leave the main thread.  So when you check the current `titleLabel`, it hasn't been updated yet and reflects the previous state.

A better approach is to use an array of `Int` to *model* your puzzle, and update the button's titles using this array.  Your `checkGameOver()` method should check the order of this array instead of the button's titles.

The general rule of thumb is: **Never use UI elements to store your state**

Comment: Thank you, vacawama! Yes,  I should have used business logic layer for this purpose. I redid the code, everything woks as it should.